# Android emulator: QEMU copy paste

Tags: macos, android-emulator, qemu

I am used to use the iPhone emulator and need to treat som Android code
How to you copy paste into the QEMU emulator on a mac. I saw something like this: adb shell input text "pbpaste". Is there no way to use normal copy paste?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't seem find other than the adb shell command as the supported option.

I would automate a shortcut with applescript and Automator Services

```
do shell script 'adb shell input text pbpaste'
```

the 'pbpaste' command gets the text from the clipboard. 'adb shell input text pbpaste' will send that text into the emulator, so you should have the input box/textarea/whatever selected in the emulator and then trigger the shortcut

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24063/create-global-shortcut-to-run-command-line-applications

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that is it. after "adb shell input text "test", how do you paste it on the emulator?

Comment: the 'pbpaste' command gets the text from the clipboard. 'adb shell input text pbpaste' will send that text into the emulator, so you should have the input box/textarea/whatever selected in the emulator and then trigger the shortcut